# How to handle null destination on message driven channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I need the Spring Integration configuration to handle the case where there will be a variable number of queues which the application will receive messages on.

Have tried the following configuration:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="dsToT2" 
    destination-name="#{tConfigurer.getDsToTQueues().values().toArray().length>2?
    dsConfigurer.getDsToTQueues().values().toArray()[2]:null}"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    channel="ackToTChannel"/>
```

but, if the destination-name resolves to null, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'destinationName' must not be null
```

What is the best way to handle this scenario?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your position. What do you want to have in case 'destination-name resolves to null' ?

Comment: if destination name is null the jms:message-driven-channel-adapter should just be non-active and ignored

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is here that you get `IllegalArgumentException` on application startup.
If really don't know if your detination will be `null` or not, you shoudl do some Java code:

1. mark your `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` with `auto-startup="false"`
2. Introduce separate bean for `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` with `autoStartup=false` too, and inject it to the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`
3. As far as `destination-name` is a property of that `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` you should right some code to resolve your destination on application startup and inject the value (if any) to the container bean.
4. And call `start()` of `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`. It is a `AbstractEndpoint` bean with id `dsToT2`

Note, you can't provide `null` to the `destination-name` attribute. Your AC will fail on startup when it tries to populate bean properties. In this case will be called `AbstractMessageListenerContainer#setDestinationName`, which, in turn, does the check
`Assert.notNull(destinationName, "'destinationName' must not be null");`.
However, you can try to provide empty string `''` instead of `null` and add similar SpEL condition for `auto-startup` attribute.

HTH

Comment: Artem, thanks, not at my PC right now but have two questions: 1)  why is the DefaultMessageListenerContainer necessary - can one not just keep it simple and call startup() on the jms message driven channel adapter? 2) could you not just put some scripting in the auto-startup of the jms adapter and, depending if the destination is null, return true or false accordingly?